# insert de dados passando apenas $_POST usando Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

partindo do pressuposto que todos os `names` dos inputs possuem o mesmo do nome da coluna do banco de dados.

```
public function create(){
    // o que está abaixo é um exemplo com os dados já populados
    $arrayDados= Input::all();
    unset($arrayDados["_token"]); 
    /*$arrayDados = array(
        "valor1" => "teste",
        "valor2" => "1234",
        "valor3"=>1234
    );
    DB::table("tabela")->insert($arrayDados );*/
    DB::table("tabela")->insert($arrayDados );
}

//HTML

<input type="text" name="valor1"/>
<input type="text" name="valor2"/>
<input type="text" name="valor3"/>

//Na tabela do banco de dados
coluna de nome: | valor1 | valor2 | valor3 |
```

Tenho 4 formulários de questionários do ENEM (variando de matéria escolar) com 100 questões cada um. Há vários `radios buttons`, `textareas` etc. na minha visão, acho trabalhoso fazer o bind de cada um dos `name's` do `html` com a coluna do banco. é uma boa prática? há alguma falha de segurança que poderia acontecer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de qualquer contacto com a base de dados o servidor deve SEMPRE validar os inputs via POST e GET, se vier de formulário HTML/URL.

Isto depende se você quer que as validações sejam iguais para todos os inputs do utilizador. Ex: Partindo do princípio que os names dos inputs do html são os mesmos que os nomes das colunas da tabela onde quer inserir os dados, e só quiser que sejam todos numéricos:

Laravel 5+:

```
public function receber_dados(Request $request) {
    $inputs = $request->except(['_token']); //todos os inputs (name => input) excpeto o crsf_token

    foreach($inputs as $key => $value) {
        $inputs[$key] = e($value); // versão curta de laravel para htmlentities, prevenção de javascript/html na nossa base de dados
        $rules[$key] = 'numeric';
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
    }

    DB::table("tabela")->insert($inputs);
    $success = 'dados inseridos';
    return ...;
}
```

Mas se quiser validações diferentes. Como por exemplo verificar se um email é unico na tabela que está na Base de Dados, ou verificar se as passwords coincidem e/ou fazer fazer hash à password aí já vai ter de tratar de cada um destes inputs 'excepcionais' à sua maneira.

Em laravel até tem a vida simplificada pois pode usar `built-ins` validations do Laravel nas validações mais comuns

Comment: Alguma razão para não utilizar o Validator do Laravel?

Comment: Claro que não, eu própio recomendo. Essa função foi só um exemplo, num projeto real deve-se usar, se é para usar um framework é para se usar o que ele nos dá, senão mais vale não usar

Comment: Mas tem toda a razão em ter apontado isso. Editei a minha resposta para que seja '100% laravel'

Comment: uma pequena dúvida: é preciso fazer algum tratamento para saber se a query foi salva com sucesso? por exemplo, se a conexão caiu no meio da transação, etc. após o ``->insert``  é preciso verificar algo? por exemplo: no ``pdo`` verificamos pelo ``if ($stmt->execute($data))``

Comment: Pode criar um `try {...} catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) { ... erro... }`